# Access to Class members in another file using rpyc without import

Tags: python, rpyc

Say in `server.py`

```
import rpyc

class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super(MyError, self).__init__(message)
        self.error = message

    def foo1(self):
        self.error_type = 1

    def foo2(self):
        self.error_type = 2


class MyService(rpyc.Service):
    def exposed_test(self):
        e = MyError('error')
        e.foo1()
        return e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadPoolServer

    server = ThreadPoolServer(MyService(), port=6000)
    server.start()
```

In `client.py`, I want to take different steps based on `error_type` like this:

```
import rpyc

with rpyc.connect('localhost', 6000) as conn:
    try:
        raise conn.root.test()
    except Exception as e:
        if e.error_type == 1:
            pass
        else:
            pass
```

However, the compiler says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python/client.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise conn.root.test()
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python/client.py", line 7, in <module>
    if e.error_type == 1:
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'error_type'
```

How can I access the member variables of such objects? It didn't work even if I change `Exception` to `BaseException`.

**Update**:
I modified `client.py` as:

```
import rpyc

with rpyc.connect('localhost', 6000) as conn:
    e = conn.root.test()
    print(e)
    print(e.error_type)
```

.`print(e)` got it right as it prints "error" but I still can't get `e.error_type`

Comment: `conn.root.test()` does not seem to return any object which derives from `BaseException`. That's the issue. Try `print()`ing it instead of `raise`ing it to see what it actually is.

Comment: What is `type(e)`? I don't know [tag:rpyc], but I'd expect that it can't unserialise to an actual instance of `MyError` without you importing that class in some fashion.

Comment: `type(e)` is `<netref class '__main__.MyError'>`

Comment: Yeah, it's an object *imitating* and proxying `MyError`, it's not really `MyError`. [tag:rpyc] is supposed to handle exception handling if you actually `raise` the exception remotely. No idea if you can make it send the "actual object" over the network; probably not, since that's conceptually weird and unreliable.

Comment: @deceze♦ thx for your patience!